# Conditional running total

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I have an interesting thing that I have to do in Redshift. Say, I have a table like this:

```
index,total,delta
0,3,null
1,5,2
2,10,5
3,11,1
4,null,4
5,null,6
6,null,2
```

where `delta` is the difference between each `total` and the previous row's `total`. Here, my `delta`s come from a different source than my `total`s, so it is possible to receive `delta`s without receiving updated `total`s.

How can I impute the `total`s according to the `delta`s? Like so:

```
index,total,delta
0,3,null
1,5,2
2,10,5
3,11,1
4,15,4
5,21,6
6,23,2
```

I'm messing around somewhere  in the vicinity of `NVL(total, LAST_VALUE(total IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY index ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) + SUM(delta) OVER (ORDER BY index ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)`, but that doesn't quite do it - I only want to `SUM` the `delta`s for which there are no corresponding `total`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
-- creating subgroups
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(total IS NOT NULL::int) OVER(ORDER BY index) s
  FROM tab
)
SELECT index, 
    CASE WHEN total IS NULL 
         THEN SUM(COALESCE(total,0) + delta) OVER(PARTITION BY s ORDER BY index)
             -FIRST_VALUE(delta) OVER(PARTITION BY s ORDER BY index)
             -- running total starting from first not null total + delta
             -- decreased by first delta
         ELSE total
    END AS total
   ,delta
FROM cte
ORDER BY index;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c9b5424e4fab6edb03c737d5c4f25da2)**

Output:

```
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ index  │ total  │ delta │
├────────┼────────┼───────┤
│     0  │     3  │       │
│     1  │     5  │     2 │
│     2  │    10  │     5 │
│     3  │    11  │     1 │
│     4  │    15  │     4 │
│     5  │    21  │     6 │
│     6  │    23  │     2 │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

**EDIT**:

Actually there is no need for `FIRST_VALUE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(total IS NOT NULL::int) OVER(ORDER BY index) s
  FROM tab
)
SELECT index, 
   CASE WHEN total IS NULL 
    THEN SUM(COALESCE(total,0) 
       + CASE WHEN total IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE delta END) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY s ORDER BY index)
    ELSE total
   END AS total
  ,delta
FROM cte
ORDER BY index;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5871a4738e72aeb0cd81f5d7e4023826)**

Comment: Amazing! That's a really clever way of bounding the SUM window function. Thanks so much!